# How can I detect an API error?

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

I am developing a Ruby application that depends on the API from the other team.

Is there a good way to print the error message indicating it is
generated from their API error?

For example, there's a method provided from the api called `foo()`
so when I do:

```
api.foo()
```

it will return an error message: `"foo error"`
when I develop my code, I want the error message to look like: `"api: foo error"`

That way, when I see this error message, then I know it's the API error,
not my code's error.

So far the best practice I can think of is to wrap around all the
methods
provided by the API, for example:

```
class apiWrap
  def initialize(api)
    @api = api
  end
  def foo
    begin
      @api.foo()
    rescue => e
      raise "api: #{e.message}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I certainly wouldn't do it by hand when you could do it using some simple metaprogramming. But I wonder what the point is; could you make *your* code's messages be more obvious?

Answer (score 0):

If in this api used its own exception class then you can redefine it like this:

```
class APIException
  alias_method :old_exception, :exception
  def exception(message)
    old_exception(message.prepend("api: ")) # for ruby 1.9.3
    old_exception("api: " + message)        # for older ruby
  end
end
```